# Spring Controllers and Dispatcher Servlet behind the scenes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How does Dispatcher Servlet works internally?

1. I have seen that **Controllers and it methods(defined by us)** can be annotated with *@RequestMapping* and many other attributes. These controller has methods that have **varying signatures (Thay can take any parameter we like).

   How does the Dispatcher servlet know how to pass these parameters in the methods defined by us? I mean how does Dispatcher Servletprepare these objects which we require in the controller methods?
2. Also what actually happens in WebApplicationContext behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

would suggest to read section [15.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) this describes internal about spring mvc framework.